# Spring Data Lovelace GA release + Spring boot release

Tags: spring-boot

Do we have any date for the Spring boot release that will include Spring Data Lovelace GA release

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2018/09/21/spring-data-lovelace-ga-released

Comment: Well I'm looking for Spring-boot GA release that includes spring-data-lovelace-ga release.